# Change child process' termination signal at runtime

Tags: linux, signals, fork, clone, sigchld

Using [`clone()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) to fork a process you can specify the signal a child process should send its parent on death instead the "normal" `SIGCHLD`.

Is it possible to change the set termination signal after the child was created? Either by the child or the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (quickly) scanned Linux' source for assignments to `struct task_struct`'s member `exit_signal`. This seems only to happen in case of reparenting, in which case there are some more checks if the set signal is sane, e.g. that [init won't receive a SIGKILL](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/24c534bb161b8c95f261b34cbe44bbd043e829fc/kernel/exit.c#L651).

That means the signal cannot be changed at runtime, most likely for security considerations.